# quill.js - Is it possible to use ng-html-bind for the editor's content?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, quill

Is it possible to use ng-html-bind for the editor's content? I am using the quill editor in my application.

```
<ng-quill-editor
    ng-model="value"
    toolbar="true"
    link-tooltip="true"
    toolbar-entries="font size bold list bullet italic underline strike align color background link"
    editor-required="true"
></ng-quill-editor>
```

As you can see, `value` is driving the content of the editor. I would like to make sure the content in the editor is not malicious i.e., script tag etc. What could be the best way to achieve this?

PS - I am new to both quill and angular.